# Python: calling asynchronous classes in async functions

Tags: python, class, asynchronous, discord.py

I am working with the discord.py module in order to make a discord bot, and it cannot handle more than one command at a time. I believe it is because it calls a class that is written synchronously. How would I restructure the following code to be asynchronous?

Discord bot command:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)

@bot.command
async def my_command(ctx, *args):
    a = MyClass(args).final_data
    # Do stuff to a and assign final result to b
    # Discord will send b as message
    await ctx.send(b)
```

My Class:

```
import requests

class MyClass:

    parameters = []
    my_session = ""
    website_data = ""
    final_data = []

    def __init__(self, args):
        self.parameters = args
        self.my_session = requests.session()

        # Loop until finished
        self.get_request(url)   # url is given by some other part of this class
        self.handle_data()

    def get_request(self, url):
        r = self.my_session.get(url)
        self.website_data = r.text

    def handle_data(self):
        # do stuff to self.website_data using self.parameters; assign final results to c
        self.final_data.append(c)
```

Comment: You can run the blocking (synchronous) code in a separate thread or process using `loop.run_in_executor`; docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

Comment: Thanks for redirecting me to loop.run_in_executor. I previously found it online, but I couldn't get it to work for syntax reasons. I tried again and managed to get the syntax right.

If anyone really wants to know my issue, I didn't correctly specify the arguments of my function. Instead of loop.run_in_executor(executor, func, *args), I did loop.run_in_executor(executor, func(*args)) or loop.run_in_executor(executor, func, (*args))

Comment: Just don't use `requests`, use an asynchronous lib such as `aiohttp` -- used by discord.py.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure but try changing `@bot.command` to `@bot.command()`